# Gsp pages preserve html tags when replacing with string

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

I am using grails 2.3

```
<td>${params?.query?name.replace(params.query,'<span>'+params.query+'</span>'):name}</td>
```

In the above statement of a gsp page, i want to highlight the name property if params.query value is available. But the generated code contains html equivalent characters.

```
<td>&lt;span&gt;Mess&lt;/span&gt;age</td>
```

how to display like below in gsp page. In 1.3 version it worked. but in 2.3 version the same code looks like above. i want to display it as,

```
<span>message</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have this setting in your Config.groovy:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "html"
```

It means that in all ${} expressions in GSPs, special HTML characters like '<' and '>' will be encoded. In general this is a reasonable setting because it prevents XSS attacks.

If you need to avoid this default behaviour for one specific expression, you can use this:

```
<td><%=params?.query?name.replace(params.query,'<span>'+params.query+'</span>'):name%></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's something you can configure in `Config.groovy`

try following setting

```
grails.views.default.codec = "html"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
<td>
<g:if test="${params?.query}">
    <span>${params.query}</span>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    ${name}
</g:else>
</td>
```